# Can the missing CLI items be re-added to Windows XP Embedded?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-xp

Can the missing CLI items be re-added to Windows XP Embedded?

Examples include: sc, ping, and ipconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to add the correct components, for example to get ping and ipconfig you need to ad the TCP/IP Utilities component.